# MsgBox Error if the number entered in certain cell is a duplicate of a number in column on another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that will enter all new registration numbers (with registars information) on one page and copy and paste the information into other worksheets for storing.

I just need to make sure that the new registration number (cell A19 on Welcome sheet) is not already in the column that stores registration numbers (column B or 2 on Registration sheet). If values are the same, exit sub.

BONUS: would be nice if I can account for an accidental space after the newly entered numbers so 1478(space) wont be added if 1478(withoutspace) exists.

Here is the script that says error 13 type mismatch when I run it:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim regisRange As Range
Set regisRange = Worksheets("Registration").Columns(2)
Range("A19").Value = r
For Each cell In regisRange
    If r = cell.Value Then
        MsgBox "The Registration Number is already in use."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: you should tell us which line is producing the error.   You can also use the Trim function to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.  I am assuming it is the line r = cell.Value  that is producing the error.   Are all cell values integers?

Comment: Wait - you declare `r`, never give it a value, then set a cell equal to the non-existent value? What's the line there for?  Also, do you need VBA? I think you could do this with a simple `CountIf()`? `=CountIf("E:E","*123*")` where you're searching for the Account "123". If it finds a match in Column E, the value will be greater than 1.  You can then just do `=If(CountIf("E:E","*123*")>1,"Match found","NO match")`.

Comment: cell is also returning an array.....

Comment: The error is Run-time error '13' Type mismatch...so yes it has something to do with the type. I just tried to convert the cell value into an integer with cInt(cell.Value) but the same error popped up.

Comment: @BruceWayne I need to do this in VBA because it is part of a larger macro that is called on when a button is pushed. It will check if the registration number already exists on another sheet and exit sub if it does - disallowing the user from entering the registration twice. And Ive given r the range("A19").value

Comment: Oh, I think you just got it backwards - switch out for this line, `r = Range("A19").Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub morestuff()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim regisRange As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Set regisRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
    r = Range("A19").Value
    For Each rcell In regisRange.Cells
        If Trim(rcell.Value) = r Then
            MsgBox "The Registration Number is already in use."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

This should work :)

there were quite a few things wrong. Incorrect sheet reference, not naming an object, and an incorrect cell reference.

I obviously changed things to make it work in my workbook, replace values to suite your needs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest instead just doing a `CountIf()`?

```
Dim r$
r = Range("A19").Value

numberOfDuplicates = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E:E"), "*" & r & "*")
If numberOfDuplicates > 0 Then
    MsgBox "The registration number is already in use"
End If
```

This avoids having to loop through an entire column, or do a "for each x", which should save time.

May need to tweak this, perhaps like `r = Trim(Range("A19").Value)`. Also, make sure you add the Worksheet references. Otherwise, this should work for you.